# How to send data only if a variable is true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm saving data in this state but I would like to send "matches" to the server only if a variable is true, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

```
   const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
       user_id: cookies.UserId,
       first_name: "",
       dob_day: "",
       dob_month: "",
       dob_year: "",
       show_gender: false,
       gender_identity: "man",
       gender_interest: "woman",
       url: "",
       about: "",
       matches: [] // send only if variable is true
   })
```

Comment: Where do you send data to the server?  Have you tried wrapping that operation in an `if` block?  It's not clear to me what you're asking or where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the sending part inside a useeffect.

```
useEffect(
        () => {
            yourVariable && sendingFucntion();
        }, 
        [yourVariable]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `matches` from your default state declaration, then, in your condition try something like this :

```js
if(true /** your condition */) {
  setFormData({
   ...formData, /** current data*/
   matches:[] /** add your key matches with correct array value.*/
  })
}
```

I guess probably something like this ? :

```js
if(matchsArray && Array.isArray(matchsArray) && matchsArray.length > 0) {
  setFormData({
   ...formData, /** current data*/
   matches:matchsArray /** add your key matches with correct array value.*/
  })
}
```

Don't forget to put your data state in a real FormData to build your POST request after. Like :

```js
const finalFormData = new FormData()

finalFormData.append(
  'data', /** your key catch by your backend api*/ 
  formData /** the react state*/
)
```

Let me know if it's help you. :)